# Process crash with gdb after hitting breakpoint in multi-threaded application using RTOS

Tags: multithreading, gdb, rtos

I am running multi-threaded program. I am trying to debug it using remote debugging. I have attached the process to the gdb and set a breakpoint in code so that breakpoint hits at location ( *location of break point present in dynamically like library*), but application crash after new thread created in dynamical link library code.

***I am running  this application on RTOS***

```
(gdb) info threads
[New Thread 1807]
[New Thread 1808]
[New Thread 1812]
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  4    Thread 1812       0x00007ffff6911eb7 in mlockall () from /lib/libc.so.6
  3    Thread 1808       0x00007ffff7bcd20d in accept () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 1807       0x00007ffff6911b69 in syscall () from /lib/libc.so.6
* 1  Thread 1804       CAppGroup::CAppGroup (this=0x65dd00, Name=..., pErrorHandlerMsgQ=0x605790) at ../../MControl/AppGroup.cpp:480
(gdb) n
481     }
(gdb) n
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 1812]

0x00007ffff68643f7 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function raise,
which has no line number information.
```

Comment: Your process didn't crash, it called `abort`. The question you should be asking at that point is "where did that call come from". And to answer it, use the GDB `where` command.

Comment: Thanks for details, In my case there was issue with RTOS system, currently it is not supporting debugging with multi-threaded application.